# weblogic.application.ModuleException:]There was a failure when processing annotations for application test.war Ensure that the annotations are valid

Tags: jsf, weblogic, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to deploy my jsf2.2 application war file on weblogic using admin console, but encountered following error. Is this something related to jsf specific libraries to be deployed under Weblogic lib folder?

```
<Sep 22, 2014 7:10:18 PM SGT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1411384203899" for task "1". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101371]There was a failure when processing annotations for application test.war  Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is null"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101371]There was a failure when processing annotations for application test.war. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is null
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:732)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:188)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:283)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:171)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:116)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:143)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:104)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: I have the same question!  -I tried upgrading from mojarra v2.1.28 (i.e., jsf-impl and jsf-api maven dependencies)  to v2.2.7.  -And, now I am getting the same vague exception.  Let me know if you find a solution!  thx!

Comment: i have the same is this solved?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue too. So, after trying diffeent kind of methods and steps available in the Web, I decided to delete WebLogic as my project's server (in Eclipse), and so, I created once again the server using the wizard.

After clenaing the server, the project, the maven dependeces, the problem was successfuly solved.

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently. My solution add below configuration to webLogic.xml file. hope it helps

```
   <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>

    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:package-name>            

    </wls:prefer-application-packages>

    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>javax.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.FacesConfigResourceProvider</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```